# The implications of a Pi-base number system

Tags: number-theory

I was just thinking about why there are 360 degrees in a circle, and why an hour is composed off 60 minutes, a minute of 60 seconds... That is, all because the Babylonians used a sexagesimal (base-60) positional numeral system.

Now I was wondering about what would happen if we used a base-Pi numeral system. I got, however, really stuck on what this means.  Does this mean a circle would be 2R, where 2 is some sort of "coordinate" like in linear algebra? Or should we just add Pi to our base-10 numeral system, and suddenly 2R has an whole other meaning?

Comment: While you're at it, why not use base e?

Comment: I considered that, but that does sound a little far fetched, doesn't it?

Comment: @JefPauwels I recommend checking out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-integer_representation for details on non-integer bases, and the references at the bottom. This is a little too loose a question for here, but since you have a general interest, you may find reading up on them of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Each number would have an expansion of the form
$$x = \pm (\ldots + x_{-1} \pi^{-1} + x_0 + x_1 \pi + x_2 \pi^2 + \ldots + x_n \pi^n)$$
where $0 \leq x_i < \pi$ with $x_i \in \mathbb{Z}$.

A circle would have a circumference of $20 D$.

Comment: This is false:  $\beta$-expansions are not necessarily unique for non-integer $\beta$

Comment: Could you please elaborate, I didn't know that.

Comment: @AdamHughes $\pi$ is not algebraic, so finite expansions are unique, no?

Comment: @Vortico I don't think I understand your response, finite expressions can never be algebraic, surely, but why would that give uniqueness of any base $\pi$ expansion?

Comment: The set $\{\pi^n : n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is linearly independent under $\mathbb{Q}$, so certainly it is independent over {0, 1, 2}.
An element with a finite base expansion as above can be written as a vector with the independent $\pi$ power basis, so it's unique.